# Excel VBA -> Userform to pick up information under loop

Tags: vba, excel, reference, userform

I am a noob when it comes to Userform creation, please kindly help.
- note: this is my first time posting and can't seem copy over of what I have on to this post 
simplified example of my current sheet:

Col A = Product Name
Col B = Qty in inventory
Col C = Allocation of product (say into different baskets)

Row 1= Apple / 10 / #1
Row 2= Orange / 10 / 5 in #2, 5 in #e

This is my biggest issue.

When I run my code:

```
for I = 1 to lastrow
    if range("C" & I) <> "#1" then
        userform1.show
    end if
next I
```

what I want to do at this point is to set label1.caption = range("C" & I) <--- ie making it dynamic 
so when the user clicks submit/ok (which should split the info into 2 separate lines instead of 1), it would go next I (to the next line) that has the allocation that is NOT #1

thanks for all your help in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easier to pass the value directly:

```
For I = 1 To lastrow
    If Range("C" & I).Value <> "#1" Then
        Load UserForm1
        UserForm1.Label1.Caption = Range("C" & I).Value
        UserForm1.Show
    End If
Next I
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to pass the value of "I" to your userform, declare it at the very top of your module, before the word "Sub":

```
Public I As Integer
Sub SearchRows()
For I = 1 To 5
If Range("C" & I) <> "#1" Then
UserForm1.Show
End If
Next I
End Sub
```

Then in the code for your userform:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Label1.Caption = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & I)
End Sub
```

This will cycle through the values in column C that are not #1.

[image]

[image]

[image]